# C++: Objects created via array, but how to pass parameters?

Tags: c++, constructor

It would be great if you could help me here: I create objects as an array

```
Class object[3];
```

but I don't know how to pass parameters by creating objects this way. If only one object would be created, the code would look like this:

```
Class object("Text", val);
```

The rest is managed by the constructor. Thanks in advance for your ideas!

Comment: Are you using the latest C++ x11 standards?

Comment: @George_Houpis yes, but if there are different versions to solve the problem, please post both of them

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754763/c-object-array-initialization-without-default-constructor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++98:

```
Class object[3] = {Class("Text1", val1), Class("Text2", val2), Class("Text3", val3)};
```

But this requires `Class` to be copy-constructible.

In C++11 it's a bit simpler and, more importantly, doesn't require `Class` to be copy-constructible:

```
Class object[3] = {{"Text1", val1}, {"Text2", val2}, {"Text3", val3}};
```

If you have more than a few objects, it's better to use `std::vector` and `push_back() / emplace_back()`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay, but is there a more convenient way (in case there are 20+ objects to create)?

Comment: @DonMan another option is to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

you variable object is not an instance of Class but an array. 
so you could use an array initialization, please look the sample below :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

class Class {
public:
    std::string val2;
    int val2;
    Class(std::string val1, int param2){
        val1 = param1;
        val2 = param2;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("%i\n", a[i]);
    }

    Class object[3] = {Class("Text1",10), Class("Text2",20), Class("Text3",30)};

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("%s %i\n", object[i].val1, object[i].val2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```