# Initializing a dynamic array of non-default constructible objects

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, language-lawyer

The code below:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int){} // no default constructor
};

int main()
{
    Foo* pFoo = new Foo[2]{1,2}; // OK in g++, fails in clang++!
    delete[] pFoo;
}
```

[compiles in gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fefb176807c24721), but [fails in clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/969a6af6e6f27a00). Is the code above syntactically correct?

Comment: Neither does wandbox. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jS7mx3XTG2xjDqb9

Comment: Just when I thought we could trust our tools. I think you broke one of them. See, this is why we can't have nice compilers.

Comment: If you are using C++11, switch to `std::vector` and use its constructor that accepts a *braced-init-list* as input: `std::vector<Foo> pFoo = {1, 2};` or maybe `std::vector<Foo> pFoo = {Foo(1), Foo(2)};`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I know that works. I wondered whether the "classic" C++ code is correct. I bumped into it when answering [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37336250/3093378).

Comment: @vsoftco: In C++03, you can only default-initialize the array items when using `new[]`. In C++11, you can initialize the individual items using specific values by using the brace syntax you showed. My guess is clang fails if it is trying to terminate the brace-init-list with a default-constructed sentry object or something like that, whereas gcc is not. Sounds like a clang bug, since the syntax itself is fine.

Comment: The code is syntactically correct: `new Foo[2]` may be followed by a brace-enclosed list.  I guess you are actually asking whether it is well-formed

Comment: @M.M No, was actually asking about the syntax, as clang failed to compile it and I observed in general that clang tends to be more standard compliant. So this made me wonder... What do you mean by "well formed"?

Comment: @vsoftco well, it is syntactically correct. clang does not give a syntax error, it says "no matching constructor".

Comment: @M.M Ohh I see what you mean, thanks, yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Looks like clang bug to me. The error messages from clang 3.8 are nonsense, e.g. "note: in implicit initialization of array element 2 with omitted initializer"

Comment: If you do actually provide a default constructor, clang doesn't call it

Comment: This looks like serious bug in `clang++` to me !!!

Comment: This program also compiles fine on VC++ 2015 see http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) says that _If initializer is a brace-enclosed list of arguments, the object is list-initialized_ .

Comment: @Destructor Which confirms that the code should be accepted (C++11 of course). I guess it's a bug in clang.

Comment: @vsoftco: definitely. You should immediately submit bug report to clang !!!

Comment: @vsoftco: behaviour of **clang++** seems so inconsistent. It allows initialization of an objects with _automatic storage duration_ . See live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da6071dea8c19ff7) .

Comment: @Destructor Filled: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27821. And yes, I know, automatic list-initialized objects are fine.

Comment: See https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22924 and the discussion therein; also http://wg21.link/cwg2102.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll turn @T.C. comment into an answer, so everyone sees what's going on without having to read through all of the comments.

This is a clang bug, the code should be accepted: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22924

Related: http://wg21.link/cwg2102