# Display void* (array) with known type and length in debugger automatically

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, debugging

Assume that type `T` and length `size` is known, 
how to display array  `data` in debugger gracefully?

```
template<class T>class Container{
    void* data;  //<-- display it!
    int size;
}
```

In watch windows (Visual studio 2015), I can display `container.data` by typing:-

```
static_cast<T*>(container.data),size
```

**Question:** Are they any technique (especially modify code in `Container`) to make this process to be automatic and elegant - like std::vector?

In other words, it would be nice if I can just type `container`, then the watch will show :-

```
container
+data           (the + button, can click to expand)
--data[0]       (expanded)
--data[1]
......
--data[size-1]
```

My best clue is to use `union`, but I am not sure.

Comment: Why not just declare `data` as `T* data;`?

Comment: I want to avoid default constructor, so I use placement new.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4756306/3577745

Comment: @javaLover default constructor of *what* ? `data` is a pointer, regardless of whether it is `T*` or `void*`. What does default construction have to do with just declaring `T* data` ? (besides the obvious, default construction *of a pointer*).

Comment: @WhozCraig   If I do that, then I will have to call ... T* data=new T[size]  --> default constructor called ...... Do I misunderstand it? ( I am new for C++)

Comment: Your use case is a bit odd, but no, it doesn't *seem* like you misunderstood. Yes, `new[T]` will indeed invoke default construction. You can avoid that with cast hijinx, but this obviously isn't the place where that is being solved, and I ultimately hope you're keeping track of what has, and has not been constructed. At least I understand what you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2015 allows debug visualization customization via custom [`.natvis`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/09/28/debug-visualizers-in-visual-c-2015/) configuration.

Among the other features it has support for the templated classes. The `Name` attribute of the `Type` element accepts an asterisk * as a wildcard character that can be used for templated class names. To refer template parameter in the visualization entry you can use `$T1` macros. Examples are located in VS2015 `Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` folder.