# Initialization of member array of non-copyable, non-movable, explicitly constructed types

Tags: c++, c++11

A library which I can't modify has a type akin to the following:

```
class A {
  public:
    A () : A(0) { }
    explicit A (int const value) : value_(value) { }

    A (A const &) = delete;
    A (A &&) = delete;

    A & operator= (A const &) = delete;
    A & operator= (A &&) = delete;

  private:  
    int value_;
}
```

Now, I have a class which requires a bunch of `A`s as members. Due to other restrictions of the environment I'm working in all of these `A`s must either be separate members or a member array (i.e. I can't use an `std::vector` to put them in or create pointers to them). I.e. my class boils down to this:

```
struct Foo {
  A a[2];
}
```

Is there any way to initialize each member with a distinct initial value? I've been trying various forms of using braced-list initialization, but they all fail due to either `A(int)` being explicit or `A` not having a copy/move-constructor.

What doesn't work:

- `Foo () : A{ { 1 }, { 2 } } { }`: won't call `A(int)` since it's `explicit`.
- `Foo () : A{ { A(1) }, { A(2) } } { }`: can't copy- nor move-assign.

**Edit:** Updated info about member array requirement.

**Edit 2:** The library in question is [SystemC](http://accellera.org/downloads/standards/systemc). My example class `A` is a port (e.g. `sc_core::sc_in`).

The reason I can't use an array of pointers is because, as far as I know, [Mentor Graphic's Questa](https://www.mentor.com/products/fv/questa) can't really deal with them. It will simulate the model correctly, but won't allow inspection of the ports. I.e. it won't be able to plot the port's values over time in a wave window. I would be very happen to be proven wrong about this, because that would allow a trivial solution to my problem.

**Edit 3:** Apparently this is a big issue anymore in a newer version of Questa. I'm not sure what changed between seeing this problem and now, could be a change to the development environment as well (which is also out of my control). In any case, my Questa now automatically names ports after their variable name (unless explicitly renamed at construction), so all is well.

Just for the sake knowing how to I'd still like to see potential solutions to the original problem though.

Comment: Why not just write a loop that allocates each A on the stack and initializes each value?

Comment: One has to ask why you have set all these restrictions on your code.

Comment: @vincent I just updated my question. Short story: creating the `A`s on the stack is not allowed. Long story: the code is used in a "debugger"-like tool written by an external company and this tool can't handle inspection of pointer members.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Thrust me, I'm not putting these restriction on the code because I want to.  The restrictions are entirely due to external libraries and (very expensive) tools.

Comment: Use array of smart pointers? Something like this `std::array<std::unique_ptr<A>,2> a{ {std::make_unique<A>(1), std::make_unique<A>(2)} };`

Comment: @tntxtnt Alas, as I put in the updated question text I can't create the members on the stack. (Or use `std::array` for that matter, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: What's stopping your from going the other of the two allowed-by-restrictions roads, the "separate members" one, i.e. (Foo() : _myMemberA1(1), _myMemberA2(2) { ... }) etc?

Comment: that class looks like example of unmaintainable code. Only thing I can imagine it is worth is to emulate some system handle's behavior (e.g. a socket handle), yet in even that case it looks pretty useless..

Comment: If we knew what the tool is, people that have used it might be better able to help.

Comment: @b.buchhold Well, there's actually about 4-6 member arrays of 8-10 elements each. Creating arrays make it much easier to deal the members that are related.

Comment: Would it be an option to derive `B` from `A` and construct array of `B`s?

`class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int value): A(value)
    {}
};`

`B b[] = {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: @NeilButterworth Updated the question.

Comment: @AlexD Hm, I guess that might actually work. The one thing I don't like about it is that it "hides" the fact that `A` is used (i.e. akin to half of the code base using `Mine::vector` instead of `std::vector`). I'll keep it in mind though!

Comment: @Darhuuk You can make a custom `MyContainer`, or `MyContainer<A>` and overload `operator[]` to return references to `A`. Or something alike. I completely understand that it is rather about selecting a smaller evil ).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> struct Foo {
>   A a[2];
> }
> ```
>
> Is there any way to initialize each member with a distinct initial
>   value? I've been trying various forms of using braced-list
>   initialization, but they all fail due to either `A(int)` being
>   explicit or `A` not having a copy/move-constructor.

You may need to use *placement-new* to create an array of `A` in some raw storage array. You then create a `std::initializer_list<ARGUMENT>` of the `ARGUMENT`s needed to construct each `A`. Something like:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size, std::size_t Alignment = alignof(T)>
struct FixedArray{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), Alignment> data[Size];

    static constexpr std::size_t size = Size;

    template<typename U>
    FixedArray(std::initializer_list<U> ls){
        assert(ls.size() <= Size && "Invalid Size"); int index = 0;
        for(auto& x : ls)
            new (&data[index++]) T(x);
    }

    FixedArray(const FixedArray&) = delete;
    FixedArray(FixedArray&&) = delete;

    A& operator[](std::size_t index){
        auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<A*>(&data) + index;
        return *std::launder(ptr);            //Sort of a legal way to alias memory C++17
    }

    ~FixedArray(){
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            this->operator[](i).~T();
    }

};
```

Then declare Foo:

```
struct Foo {
    FixedArray<A, 4> a;
};
```

To create `Foo` having `A(546)`, `A(99)`, `A(-4)`, `A(0)`:

```
int main() {
    Foo f{{546, 99, -4, 0}};
    return 0;
}
```

See a working [**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2bdc54fd66d8d7b)

---

After testing with GCC 6.3 at `-O3` optimization levels, about exactly the same assembly is generated for using `FixedArray` vs plain raw arrays, See it on [gcc.godbolt.com](https://godbolt.org/g/bv0VFF).

Comment: Neat. I'm afraid the tool won't support it, but it's worth a try.

Comment: +1: nice answer. I think the `A`s in `operator[]` should actually be `T`s though. Also, is there a way to make this work with types whose constructor takes more than one argument?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve the problem as follows (also using SystemC, here my non-copyable, non-movable items are sc_modules):

```
class Object : sc_module {
    Object(sc_module_name name){}
};

class Container : sc_module {

    std::array<Object, 3> objects;

    Container(sc_module_name name) :
    objects{{{"object1"},{"object2"},{"object3"}}}
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer - no. The longer answer - kind of, but its disgusting.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754763/object-array-initialization-without-default-constructor) discussion.