# Initialization of an array of non-moveable objects: why does such code fail to compile on GCC?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, language-lawyer

Here is the code example where `Test` is a non-copyable *and* non-moveable class with some `virtual` members and a user-defined constructor, and `B` is a class that contains a raw (C-style) array of `Test` objects:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() = delete;

    Test(const Test&) = delete;
    Test(Test&&) = delete;
    Test& operator=(const Test&) = delete;
    Test& operator=(Test&&) = delete;

    Test(int a, int b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}
    virtual ~Test() {}

    int a_;
    int b_;
};

//----------------

class B
{
public:
/*(1)*/ B() : test_{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} {} // Does not compile on GCC, but compiles on Clang and MSVC

private:
        Test test_[2];
};

//---------------- 

int main()
{
        B b;
/*(2)*/ Test test[2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; // Successfully compiles on GCC, Clang and MSVC
}
```

I want to initialize `B`'s internal array `test_` using the braced initialization syntax (line `/*1*/`), so that each of the two `Test` objects would be constructed in-place, without needing to create a temporary and then move it.

On Clang and MSVC, this code compiles without warnings.

But GCC's behavior confuses me: it fails to compile the line `/*1*/`, while successfully compiling the line `/*2*/`, where I am using the same syntax to initialize a local array. Yet for compiling the first line, it still requires the deleted move constructor of class `Test`.

The question is, why? Does the C++ standard clearly define whether these lines `/*1*/` and `/*2*/` should compile at all? If it does, which of the compilers is right from the standard's point of view? Can this inconsistent behavior be called a GCC bug, or do Clang and MSVC overlook some checks that they are supposed to perform?

I can understand that GCC might require a move constructor in order to create a temporary `Test` object from the inner braces (`{1, 2}`), and then *move* that object into an array. Hence the compilation error. But if that is so, why does it *not* fail on the line `/*(2)*/` for the very same reason? This is the most confusing thing to me in this example.

---

By the way, here's an interesting observation: if I replace the definition of `test_` with `std::array<Test, 2>` (instead of a "C-style" array), and replace the code in the constructor's initialization list with `test_{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}`, everything starts to compile successfully on all three mentioned compilers.

It is also unclear to me why does GCC *not* fail in this case on any line, while failing with a "raw" array.

Can anyone explain this as well?

Comment: Related, almost duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473777/

Comment: This also compiles with g++, if `Test` has no virtual members: https://godbolt.org/z/qQSOwS

Comment: @chtz Looks similar, but I can't find answers to my questions there -- only some suggested workarounds (which I'm not interested in, since I've already found one). So I hope that someone would explain why does the constructor fail to compile on GCC in my example, while the initialization of an array in `main` compiles successfully, and is that correct that the other two compilers compile this code without warnings. Why such inconsistency, what does the C++ standard tell about it (if it does at all), which compiler is right, etc.

Comment: @chtz True, virtual members make the difference. I will update the question accordingly to make it more clear.

Comment: If you want to know which compiler is right, maybe add the `[language-lawyer]` tag.

Comment: @chtz  Added it. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List-initialization of an array without temporaries - not working in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904342/list-initialization-of-an-array-without-temporaries-not-working-in-gcc)

Comment: @chtz  BTW, it's not the `virtual` keyword that matters here, but the fact that the destructor is user-defined. Non-virtual `~Test() {}` does not compile as well. But `~Test() = default;` compiles successfully. Hovewer, `virtual ~Test() = default;` fails with the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no problem with the initialization, so I think this is a GCC bug.

---

The initialization involved is list-initialization, so we consult [[dcl.init.list]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined
>   as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - ([3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3.3)) Otherwise, if `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is
>     performed.
> - [...]

(An array is an aggregate.)  Now we go to [[dcl.init.aggr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#3):

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list as specified
>   in [dcl.init.list], the elements of the initializer list are taken as
>   initializers for the elements of the aggregate, in order. **Each
>   element is copy-initialized from the corresponding
>   *initializer-clause*.** If the *initializer-clause* is an expression and a narrowing conversion is required to convert the expression, the
>   program is ill-formed.

So, for either of the two elements, we are effectively doing `Test a = {1, 2}`, which is valid because `Test(int, int)` is not explicit.  Therefore, the initialization is well-formed and should be accepted by the compiler.