# C++ Create objects in a loop with a given constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

I was on my way to create a class that would mimic `std::vector` to a certain extend.

I quickly faced a problem where I couldn't create an array of objects which didn't have a default constructor. I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4756306/8106847 which allowed me to do just that. But the problem now is I'm stuck to one certain constructor.

How do I pass any constructor like 
`std::vector<Obj>(100, Obj(1, "str"))`
does ?

(or is it far too complicated for anyone who's not senior C++ developer?)

Comment: So you want to create a 100 objects that are initialized with the same values but are different objects?

Comment: You don't pass constructor, you pass an object and make copies of it.

Comment: @KamilCuk I guess I was looking at it quite a wrong way... Could you point me somewhere where I could see how to copy an object in this fashion?

Comment: Sure, learn [from the bests](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/vector#L2614). Just allocate memory with `new Obj[100]` and use `std::fill` or `std::fill_n` to fill it with some value. `std::fill` is just assignment.

Comment: Huh, I guess the best place to look for a way to mimic vector is vector itself, thank you kind sir.

Comment: But doesn't `new Obj[100]` require it to have a default constructor?

Comment: Indeed you are right. You would have to use something along `reinterpret_cast<Obj*>(operator new(sizeof(Obj) * num, alignof(Obj)));` to allocate bytes only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you exactly want but if you want to initialize the list with some default values and then use a different way to construct others, you can manipulate the list however you want. Let me elaborate more:

Suppose this is how you've defined your `Obj` (in the future, it'd be helpful to include your implementation of `Obj`)

```
class Obj {
public:
  explicit Obj(int arg1, std::string arg2) : arg1_(arg1), arg2_(std::move(arg2)) {}
  explicit Obj(std::string arg2) : arg1_(25), arg2_(std::move(arg2)) {}

private:
  int arg1_;
  std::string arg2_;
};
```

Now vectors can take a capacity and an optional default value.
If your type doesn't have a constructor that takes no values, you can't create the vector like this (without specifying the default value so you have to pass the default value by creating one instance of that object using whatever constructor you want). You can always create an empty vector and then add items to it one by one. To enhance performance, if you know how many items you're going to have, you can reserve memory spots for them but don't add them just yet. This way, you don't have to worry about constructor because no objects will be created just yet. The last code snipped in this post demonstrates how to do this.
If you have an int, you can do this:

```
std::vector<int> myInts{50, 1};  // make a vector of 50 items with default value of 1
myInts[1] = 26;  // change the second value to be 26.
```

You can do the same thing with `Obj`

```
Obj defaultValue{100, "Type1"};
std::vector<Obj> myObjs{50, defaultValue};  // make a vector of 50 Objs with copies of defaultValue.
```

Note that these are copies so if you change one of them, it won't change the other ones. The following is the same as above but it's in one line (passing rvalue instead of lvalue).

```
std::vector<Obj> myObjs{50, Obj{100, "Type1"}};  // same thing as above.
```

Now if you want some items to be constructed differently, you can assign different values.

```
std::vector<Obj> myObjs{50, Obj{100, "Type1"}};
myObjs[0] = Obj{"Type2"};
```

If you have a lot of different ways of initializing this. Then what you can do is to avoid creating the list with a default value and add items to the vector one by one.

```
std::vector<Obj> myObjs;
myObjs.reserve(100);  // expand the capacity but don't actually create any items.
myObjs.push_back(Obj{10, "Type1"});
myObjs.push_back(Obj{"Type2"});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I said I am trying to mimic vector which means not using it.

Comment: so you want to create an array of Objs? like `Obj[]`?

Comment: In that case, I'd advise doing more or less what vector does, take the default value and make copies of it to create the array.

Comment: That's actually what I might be looking for. Could you show me where I could learn how to create such copies? (of objects without copy constructor of course)