# class templates 'no matching function for call to Player::Player()'

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm learning about data structures by making a simple card game.
In this code, i have a class **Player**, and a **Queue** containing all the players in the game.

the implementation of the Queue:

```
template < typename T >
    class Queue{
    int count;
    int front, rear;
    T entry[maxsize];
    public:
    Queue();
    bool empty();
    errorcode Append(T item);
    errorcode serve();
    errorcode retreive(T &item);
    };
```

The Queue constructor:

```
template <typename T>
    Queue<T>::Queue(){
        count = 0;
        rear = maxsize-1;
        front=0;
    }
```

And here is the Player class:

```
       class Player {
            int number;
            List<string> set;
        public:
            Player(int number, List<string> set) {
                this->number = number;
                this->set = set;
            }
            void draw();
            string play();
            .
            .
            .
        };
```

in the main function, i declare the Queue using this code:

```
Queue<Player> pl;
```

But i get the error 'no matching function for call to Player::Player()', this error is in the line where the queue constructor is implemented.

Comment: Does `Player` class have a default constructor you are trying to call?

Comment: No, i forgot to, your comment solved my problem!.. thanks!.

Answer (score 2):

It's what it says (and has little to do with templates).

`Queue<Player>` has a member `Player entry[maxsize]`, which requires the default-construction of `maxsize` `Player` objects.

But since `Player` has no default constructor, this is impossible.

[How about a nice vector instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4754763/560648) You don't really need/want to allocate the maximum number of `Player`s up-front anyway, surely.

Comment: oh :(, it took me long time trying to find where the problem is, now it's solved!, thanks!.