# Making class to call the right constructor when used

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class `Array` which has the following constructor:

```
explicit Array(int size = 0, const T &v = T()) {
    if (size < 0) {
        throw ArrayExceptions::InvalidLength();
    }
    Array::size = size;
    array = new T[size];
    insertValueIntoArray(size,v);
}
```

In some other class `DataController` I have:

```
Array<Data> dataArray;
int dataAmount;

explicit DataController(int length) : dataArray(length), dataAmount(length) {}
```

But `Data.h` does not have a constructor without arguments so the compiler complaints on `const T &v = T()` of `Array.h`:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Data::Data()'
```

Instead it has the following constructor:

```
Data(int length) : length(length), /** Other constructor calls ...  **/ {}
```

What should I change in order to make the `Array` use the `Data(length)` constructor insead of the `Data()`?
I can modify all the files.

I have tried to switch it to:

```
explicit DataController(int length) : dataArray(length, Data(length)), dataAmount(length) {}
```

but then I get the same error in line:

```
array = new T[size];
```

Minimal example:

```
template<typename T>
class Array {
    int size;
    T *array;

public:
    explicit Array(int size = 0, const T &value = T()) {
        Array::size = size;
        array = new T[size];
    }

    ~Array() {
        delete[] array;
    }
};

class Data {
private:
    int length;

public:
    Data(int length) : length(length) {}

};

class DataController {
private:
    Array<Data> dataArray;
    int dataAmount;

public:

    explicit DataController(int length) : dataArray(length), dataAmount(length) {}
};
```

Please suggest solutions without using the `std` if you can.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why don't you a signed int instead of an unsigned int? The size parameter would then never be lower than 0.

Comment: There are different ways to solve this problem. It is impossible to tell what you want without a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object array initialization without default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754763/object-array-initialization-without-default-constructor)

Comment: I have added a minimal example, please check it if you can

Comment: I suggest changing the definition of Data to be class `Data { private: int length; public: Data(int length=0) : length(length) {} };`

Comment: Off-topic: `if (size < 0) { throw ArrayExceptions::InvalidLength(); }` – well, right. Negative sizes are meaningless. But you wouldn't have to care for if you would have used *unsigned* type right from the start. That's what these types are for. And most appropriate type for size/length specifications is `size_t`...

Comment: You should get used to consistently implement the constructors initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`): `Array(size_t size, ...) : size(size), array(new T[size]) { }` (assuming you made the exception obsolete already; if not, then, of course, you cannot create the array there). You this way prefer direct initialisation by value over default initialisation + later asignment (which can be more costly for complex types). Some types *only* can be initialised that way (references, const members, non-default-constructible types).

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues in your code.

The first is the default value of `v` in `Array` is `T()` which requires a default constructor. This is easily solved by just not using the default parameter:

```
dataArray(length, Data(length))
```

The second more complicated issue is then that:

```
array = new T[size]
```

calls the default constructor for each element in `array`. The simplest solution is to use an existing class that handles this for you like `std::vector`. If you want to implement it yourself you'll need to allocate memory using `malloc`, `::operator new` or maybe [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) then use placement new to initialise each element to a copy of `v`. You'll need to keep track of both how many elements you've allocated and how many you have initialised then call the destructors only for the initialised elements.

Comment: This is the only place where I use `Array`. So what would be the fastest solution? Would it be to make changes in `Array`? If so, how should I do it?

Comment: The fastest, safest and best solution would be to let the standard library do the work for you and use `std::vector`, you could probably even just replace your `Array` class with `std::vector`

Comment: unfortunately, I can't use the `std` library. I thought of changing the arguments of Array and the call of `new`?

Comment: If you can't use the standard library (I don't understand why people trying to teach c++ don't let their students use c++) then you'll need to look here for how to do it manually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754763/object-array-initialization-without-default-constructor

Comment: @AlanBirtles Actually I don't think it's that a bad idea if students learn about the internals of `std::vector` and similar. My criticism rather is that they go over to that *far* too early (and using int instead of size_t is a proof for that this has happened here as well...); that shouldn't be covered at all before using the standard library has got just as natural as using a tooth brush in the morning...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `new T[size]`, you can allocate uninitalised memory then copy-construct `T`s into it.

```
template<typename T>
class Array {
    struct aligned_storage {
        struct type {
            alignas(alignof(T)) unsigned char data[sizeof(T)];
        };
    };
    using storage_t = aligned_storage::type;
    int size;
    storage_t * storage;

    void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            reinterpret_cast<T*>(storage.data[i])->~T();
        delete[] data;
    }

public:
    explicit Array(int size = 0, const T & value = T())
        : size(size), storage(new storage_t[size])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            new (storage.data[i]) T(value);
    }

    Array(const Array & other) 
        : size(other.size), storage(new storage_t[other.size])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            new (data[i]) T(other[i]);
    }

    Array(Array && other) 
        : size(other.size), storage(other.storage)
    {
        other.size = 0;
        other.data = nullptr;
    }

    Array& operator=(Array other) 
    {
        clear();
        storage = other.storage;
        size = other.size;
    }

    ~Array() {
        clear();
    }

    T& operator[](int pos) {
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(storage.data[pos]);
    }

    const T& operator[](int pos) const {
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(storage.data[pos]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Hmm nice idea. Why do you use `free` instead of `delete`? Also, how should the `operator=` look like?

Comment: @vesii because `free` goes with `aligned_alloc`. It's undefined behaviour to `delete` (or `delete[]`) a `void *`

Comment: I'm actually new to `aligned_alloc`. Is it similar to `malloc`? If so, it is possible to switch it to `malloc`?

Comment: @vesii Yes, it does something similar to malloc, but also ensures the result has the specified alignment. This is necessary for over-aligned `T`s

Comment: I see. So I guess it is not possible to change to malloc? Also I get an error "An attribute list cannot appear here" for `alignas(alignof(T)) char[sizeof(T)]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206020/discussion-between-caleth-and-vesii).