# Calling parameterized constructor while creating array of objects in heap

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

```
class A{
    int a;
public:
    A(int i){
        a=i;
    }
};


class B{
    int b;
    A *arrA;
public:
    B(int n){
        b=n;
        arrA=new A[n];
    }
};
```

Now, I want to send 'n' to the constructor of all objects of A being created using 'new' in B.
How can I do it?

Comment: This help you out: [Object array initialization without default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754763/object-array-initialization-without-default-constructor)?

Comment: you can use `std::vector`

Comment: `vector` would set all of the elements to the same value unless you do some really spooky stuff.

Comment: @idclev463035818 if there is any way without using vector?

Comment: @user4581301 OP wants to pass the same `n` to all elements constructors

Comment: why don't you want to use `std::vector`?

Comment: `std::vector` does correctly manage the dynamic memory, your class does not ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ja. I misread the code. Somehow my brain put in extra garbage.

Comment: @letsShareKnowlede you would have to use [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new), and that's somewhere you do not want to go without a very good reason and a fair amount of experience with C++. I think one of the answers in the link I dropped into the first comment  covers it. Use the `vector` though. The pain level will be several orders of magnitude lower.

Comment: @user4581301 I want to do it once without using vector and the answers in the link don't really clear it for me. Maybe I am unable to get them.

Comment: @idclev463035818 If it can be done without using vector?

Comment: @letsShareKnowlede It cannot be done without reimplementing the features of `std::vector` that would allow you to do it or similar. Why don't you want to use `std::vector` ?

Comment: The placement `new` example in the second answer is about as simple as they come, unfortunately. Can it be done without `vector`? Yes, but you'll find you pretty much rewrote `vector`.